How come I don't see yolo.yaml file in my yolov9 folder when trying to train data in G.C it expects that file
I've come across a problem.
I'm doing object detection on Google Colab with the CNN Yolov9. I'm running into issues because I'm trying to train the data using a command, but the error is saying:
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2024-07-18 02:23:06.278402: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT train: weights=/content/yolov9/models/detect/yolo.yaml, cfg=yolo.yaml, data=/content/unzip_test/data.yaml, hyp=data/hyps/hyp.scratch-low.yaml, epochs=30, batch_size=16, imgsz=640, rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, noval=False, noautoanchor=False, noplots=False, evolve=None, bucket=, cache=ram, image_weights=False, device=, multi_scale=False, single_cls=True, optimizer=SGD, sync_bn=False, workers=8, project=runs/train, name=exp, exist_ok=False, quad=False, cos_lr=False, flat_cos_lr=False, fixed_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, patience=100, freeze=[0], save_period=-1, seed=0, local_rank=-1, min_items=0, close_mosaic=0, entity=None, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, artifact_alias=latest Traceback (most recent call last): File "/content/yolov9/train.py", line 634, in <module> main(opt) File "/content/yolov9/train.py", line 503, in main check_file(opt.data), check_yaml(opt.cfg), check_yaml(opt.hyp), str(opt.weights), str(opt.project)  # checks File "/content/yolov9/utils/general.py", line 452, in check_yaml return check_file(file, suffix) File "/content/yolov9/utils/general.py", line 478, in check_file assert len(files), f'File not found: {file}'  # assert file was found AssertionError: File not found: data/hyps/hyp.scratch-low.yaml
............
This is the command I executed:
import torch
import os
!pip install TensorFlow
!python train.py --img 640 --single-cls --batch 16 --epochs 30 --data /content/unzip_test/data.yaml --weights /content/yolov9/models/detect/yolo.yaml  --cache 
Note:

unzip_test is just a folder name.
I've looked in every folder and file of yolov9, but I haven't found it.
I've imported a file named yolo.yaml into the model's folder, but it didn't work.
I've tried testing for similar weights but it's mainly looking for a specific file named yolo.yaml.

